# C program traffic light please?

Tags: c

I have to write a short program in C ,which takes the state of the traffic lights  (if it's green or red) and displays the action that we have to do ( pass the road/stop).In my opinion,we have to use the if clause here..
So I wrote this in C but when I run it,it displays "Red.." and if I try to press something,it shows only "Green"..What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

        int red,green;
        printf(" red :");
        scanf("%d",&red);
        printf(" green :");
        scanf("%d",&green);
        if ( red ){
                printf(" Stop %d\n",red);
        }
        else{
                printf("Pass the road - %d\n",green);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really hope you don't work for google on the "Google Car" project :)

Comment: Maybe in the future,all these hours sweating over c will be worth it,and I will work for google :D

Comment: Meanwhile,can you help me??

Comment: Was about to tag this "homework", but that tag is "disallowed" haha. Does that mean we should close this question then?

Comment: I will add that tag,I havent disallowed anything.No need to be ironical.

Comment: I can't tag it either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider how the user will describe the current state of the light. instead of asking is it red? and checking if he put a non-zero integer which means yes, you could ask for the user to type the color. then depending on what he typed you show the appropriate message.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char colorName[128];
    printf(" What color is the light: ");
    scanf("%s", colorName);

    if ( strcmp(colorName, "red") == 0 ){
         printf(" Stop!\n");
    }else  if ( strcmp(colorName, "green") == 0 ){
         printf("cross the road\n");
    }else {
         printf("is %s even a color?\n", colorName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I considered it because you should have *helped* user2304286 complete the homework assignment rather than simply doing it for him or her, and you haven't explained your answer at all.

Answer (score 4):

You have used an integer with the if condition.
In C, any positive integer, that evaluates inside the if statement is considered to be true.

```
if(some positive number)
{
// always true
}
else
{
//control never reaches here
}
```

One workaround may be to use specific values, for different conditions.

For Example, try this

```
    if ( red == 1){
            printf(" Stop %d\n",red);
    }
    else{
            printf("Pass the road - %d\n",green);
    }
```

Now, your if condition has a specific and better entry  condition, where only one specific number corresponds to a given condition. You can go ahead and add conditions for printing the green statement using the `else-if` , or let it be a default condition.

A similar implementation using switch-case would be:

```
switch(red)
{
case 1:  printf(" Stop %d\n",red);
         break;

default: printf("Pass the road - %d\n",green);
         break;
}
```

Comment: yes that is expected, because if red is not 1, it is always "pass the road" condition

Answer (score 2):

You request input of type integer with `%d`.

According to C's boolean logic, 0 is false and !0 is true. So unless you input 0 as the first integer, you will always end up in the first clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
   int gd = DETECT, gm, midx, midy;

   initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

   midx = getmaxx()/2;
   midy = getmaxy()/2;

   setcolor(RED);
   settextstyle(SCRIPT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
   settextjustify(CENTER_TEXT, CENTER_TEXT);
   outtextxy(midx, midy-10, "Traffic Light Simulation");
   outtextxy(midx, midy+10, "Press any key to start");
   getch();
   cleardevice();
   setcolor(WHITE);
   settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 1);
   rectangle(midx-30,midy-80,midx+30,midy+80);
   circle(midx, midy-50, 22);
   setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,RED);
   floodfill(midx, midy-50,WHITE);
   setcolor(BLUE);
   outtextxy(midx,midy-50,"STOP");
   delay(2000);
   graphdefaults();
   cleardevice();
   setcolor(WHITE);
   rectangle(midx-30,midy-80,midx+30,midy+80);
   circle(midx, midy, 20);
   setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,YELLOW);
   floodfill(midx, midy,WHITE);
   setcolor(BLUE);
   outtextxy(midx-18,midy-3,"READY");

   delay(2000);
   cleardevice();
   setcolor(WHITE);
   rectangle(midx-30,midy-80,midx+30,midy+80);
   circle(midx, midy+50, 22);
   setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,GREEN);
   floodfill(midx, midy+50,WHITE);
   setcolor(BLUE);
   outtextxy(midx-7,midy+48,"GO");
   setcolor(RED);
   settextstyle(SCRIPT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 4);
   outtextxy(midx-150, midy+100, "Press any key to exit...");

   getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. I assume this is an answer to the problem - it looks like a completely new implementation to my untrained eye. Please consider providing a brief explanation of what it does and how it helps the questioner.